# What does it mean if I reimage an Azure VM scale set?

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I have a vm scale set deployed using a custom image.
What will happen if I re-image it? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/reimage) aren't very helpful here.

How does it differ from deleting and redeploying via ARM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the custom image you want to use for your vm scale set.

Specifically, in the ARM template (or CLI/PS script), you can specify an image ID like this:

"storageProfile": {
"imageReference": {
"id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{existing-custom-image-name}"
},

Refer to the thread here:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16899 
Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: I see thanks. Someone else experiencing the issue that when the custom image gets updated (but under old name), and vmss redeploys, the old image still is used?